# why my code is getting time excedded in "decrease to zero" problem

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-programming

Trying to solve [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/down-to-zero-ii/problem) problem.

You are given Q queries. Each query consists of a single number N. You can perform 2 operations on N in each move. If N=a×b(a≠1, b≠1), we can change N=max(a,b) or decrease the value of N by 1. Determine the minimum number of moves required to reduce the value of N to 0.

Could you suggest how can I improve my code?

```
int downToZero(int n) {
int dp[n+1];
dp[0]=0;dp[1]=1;dp[2]=2;dp[3]=3;
for(int i=4;i<=n;i++)
{
    dp[i]=dp[i-1]+1;
    for(int j=2;j*j<=i;j++)
    {
        if(i%j==0)
        {
            int fac=max(j, i/j);
            dp[i]=min(dp[i], dp[fac]+1);
        }
    }

}
return dp[n];

}
```

Comment: Is there a problem with the code? Otherwise it might be better to ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: One suggestion: add checks. If `n < 2`, then you have a problem.

Comment: I don't think dp is necessary. If it's even reduce it to `2` and then the next step it becomes `1`. If it's odd subtract one and then reduce it to two. Any prime number `p` will take `p` steps, reducing `n` to any number that's not 2 is suboptimal, since it's always only one step away from an even number, and 3 will take one more step to get to zero than 2.

Comment: `int dp[n+1];` is not valid C++ (although it may be a compiler extension for your particular platform).

Comment: So either your algorithm is not the best algorithm, or you can try and make the code you have faster. Is the best algorithm really to solve all the values up to N? Would it be better to find all the primes up to N, and use that as the basis?

Comment: Can you avoid some of the divide operations (% and /) by deduction from the previous iteration? Divide operations are still relatively slow on modern processors. When does i%j give a different answer than i%(j-1)? What about i/j? In your max(), do you know if max is a template function or a macro? if j*j is < i, when can i/j be less than j?

Comment: I wish I could upvote the previous comment concerning your usage of invalid C++ syntax twice.  According to the problem, the value of `N` can be up to 1000000.  That non-standard `dp[n+1]` you have in the code can easily blow out the stack.  Change that to `std::vector<int> dp(n+1);`.

Comment: Also, as soon as you write a nested loop and submit your answer, you can practically say "I give up, give me the timeout error I deserve".  Sites such as hackerrank gives questions that have naïve, very easy, but very slow solutions that almost never work due to timeout issues.  The goal of the questions is for you to figure out a better algorithm and/or use a better data structure than the naïve nested loop solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The bit that is too slow is:

```
for(int j=2;j*j<=i;j++)
{
    if(i%j==0)
```

You are scanning linearly to find factors. There has to be a better way. Keeping a list of primes, for example.